# Chrome can only start every second time

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

#### The problem

Starting today, I notice that google chrome suddenly starts only every other time that I try to open the problem.

1. I try to open chrome: Nothing happens, I do see a little waiting circle for 1 second like the computer is thinking about it
2. I try to open chrome again: It opens
3. I try to open chrome: Nothing happens, I do see a little waiting circle for 1 second like the computer is thinking about it
4. I try to open chrome again: It opens

And so on, it does not appear to matter whether there is already an open chrome window or how long I wait between attempts. I did not install any software/plugins and this problem only happens with google chrome.

#### What have I tried

I searched for this, but only found that it may be the settings. Here are the things that I tried and did not help:

1. Disable all extensions
2. Change the home page (from empty tab to google)
3. Disable phishing protection
4. Update chrome (34.0.1847.45 beta-m)
5. Restart the computer
6. [Deleting the user profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059)

#### The question

I have tried everything I could think of to deal with this problem. Is there anything left to try?

If any relevant information is missing don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: The only thing I don't see you trying is deleting the user profile.  Make sure your not using a pre-release to many variables if you do that.

Comment: @Ramhound Deleting the profile did not help, but going for the stable version worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

After realizing that I was on a beta version, I tried to get back to the normal (34.0.1847.45 m) version via [the chrome download page](http://chrome.google.com).

This solved the problem.